# To find comments to my questions and to answers of my questions

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface

At moment, there is only one efficient way to find comments to your answers and questions: to go through each question one-by-one.

The indication of active-envelope is useless, since it is delayed.
It also gives no indication of comments to your answers or questions or to the comments of your questions' answers.

The problem seems to be in the following box

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/so-comment-response-bug.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/so-comment-response-bug.png)

*Anwer responses* indicates me that I have answers for my questions.
*Comment responses* then again suggests me that I have comments in my questions OR in comments in my questions' answers.

If I click both the values `18` and `13`, the landing page is exactly the same. That is URLs are the same in `18` and `13`.

It does not make sense for me to use such a notification system.

This is the reason why I am not using the box at all.

**Please, fix the bug in the URLs.**

Answer (score 4):

Even though the indicator flag on the envelope is somewhat useless, it still gives the correct responses if you click on it. That's what I always do - just periodically click on the envelope to find recent activity and look at the comments and answers which have been posted.

Yes, you get both comments and answers in the same list - but is that really a big deal for you? I'd want to go through both sets anyway, so I really don't mind them being intermingled. It means there's only one list for me to look through rather than two.

Comment: Good point! However, it sometimes happens to me that I have not read all comments related to my questions. For instance, I read one comment 3 months too late once. - To have the comments and answers in separate lists would likely minimize the problem. - I need data first before making any conclusions which is the best way, since we have not tested my suggestion.